# How to read a csv dataset with multipoint column in sf

Tags: r, csv, sf

i have a csv with a multipoint WGS84 column:

head(df, n=3)

```
          CUP                                      the_geom
        <chr>                                         <chr>
1 F11B00000210001                         (16.578441,40.669874)
2 F11B01000360001                         (16.390963,39.752256)
3 F11B04000210001 ((15.229943,40.441221),(15.889952,40.516008))
```

I'm trying to get the geometries from it, and i think that "the_geom" could be a simple feature column.
So i try to read it with sf package:

```
df_ st_read(dsn = 'data,csv', geometry_column = the_geom)
```

but i get this error:

```
Error in st_sf(x, ..., agr = agr) : no simple features geometry column present
```

I think i must change something the column strings, but i don't know so much about sf.

There is a solution?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to convert your coordinate strings into WKT format. Valid MULTIPOINT WKT strings look like this:

```
MULTIPOINT((-122.360 47.656), (-122.343 47.656))
```

You might be able to do this on your strings with some string matching and replacement, or you might have to decompose your strings into parts and then reassemble as a valid WKT. Note especially the *blank spaces* between the X and Y coordinates!

Worked example - the data:

```
> d
  V1              V2                                            V3
1  1 F11B00000210001                         (16.578441,40.669874)
2  2 F11B01000360001                         (16.390963,39.752256)
3  3 F11B04000210001 ((15.229943,40.441221),(15.889952,40.516008))
```

Then this beast turns commas to spaces, then replaces the spaces that were dropped between the brackets between the multipoints, and pastes "MULTIPOINT" onto it to make a valid WKT, then feeds it to `st_as_sfc` to create simple features things:

```
> st_as_sfc(paste0("MULTIPOINT",gsub("\\) \\(","\\),\\(",gsub(","," ",d$V3))))
Geometry set for 3 features 
geometry type:  MULTIPOINT
dimension:      XY
bbox:           xmin: 15.22994 ymin: 39.75226 xmax: 16.57844 ymax: 40.66987
epsg (SRID):    NA
proj4string:    NA
MULTIPOINT(16.578441 40.669874)
MULTIPOINT(16.390963 39.752256)
MULTIPOINT(15.229943 40.441221, 15.889952 40.51...
>
```