# Convert CSV file with long and lat geometry column to sf object in R

Tags: r, geometry, csv

I can't seem to find the answer to this anywhere. How can I read in and convert a CSV file with geometry column containing long/lat to sf object. Here is the `dput` for the file

```
structure(list(date = c("2017-08-04", "2017-08-04", "2017-08-04", "2017-08-04", "2017-08-04", "2017-08-04"),
               is_boarded = c("0", "0", "0", "0", "1", "0"), 
               fire = c("0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0"), 
               homeless = c("0", "0", "1", "1", "0", "0"), 
               address = c("1231 N harding ave", "5942 S peoria st", "6440 S seeley ave", "6428 S paulina st", "9015 S houston ave", "10917 S buffalo ave"), 
               zip_code = c("60651", "60621", "60636", "60636", "60617", "60617"), 
               ward = c("37", "16", "16", "15", "10", "10"), 
               community_area = c("23", "68", "67", "67", "46", "52"), 
               geometry = c("c(-87.7251002085875, 41.903236038454)", "c(-87.6473828702868, 41.7862165473861)", "c(-87.6750561873273, 41.7767719172303)", "c(-87.6666233031588, 41.7770234233244)", "c(-87.5499059450373, 41.731640678147)", "c(-87.5437832254962, 41.6970145984798)"), 
               PRI_NEIGH = c("Humboldt Park", "Englewood", "Englewood", "Englewood", "South Chicago", "East Side")
               ),
          row.names = c(NA, 6L), 
          class = "data.frame"
         )
```

Comment: Why your geometry seems to contains a stringify vector if you read it from a CSV? I'm unable to get the same result for geometry using my own sample with a column with both lon, lat values for the same column

Comment: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/251998/how-to-read-a-csv-dataset-with-multipoint-column-in-sf

Comment: @ThomasG77...the csv came in this format and I read it in with read.csv.

Comment: @GISKid, I read the above solution but since my geometry column is slightly different, I am not sure how to translate to my particular case

Comment: @ify I have added an answer that explains how to adapt it in this case, hope it helps!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here's one way to approach it:

```
library(sf)
library(dplyr)

data=structure(list(date = c("2017-08-04", "2017-08-04", "2017-08-04", "2017-08-04", "2017-08-04", "2017-08-04"),
               is_boarded = c("0", "0", "0", "0", "1", "0"), 
               fire = c("0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0"), 
               homeless = c("0", "0", "1", "1", "0", "0"), 
               address = c("1231 N harding ave", "5942 S peoria st", "6440 S seeley ave", "6428 S paulina st", "9015 S houston ave", "10917 S buffalo ave"), 
               zip_code = c("60651", "60621", "60636", "60636", "60617", "60617"), 
               ward = c("37", "16", "16", "15", "10", "10"), 
               community_area = c("23", "68", "67", "67", "46", "52"), 
               geometry = c("c(-87.7251002085875, 41.903236038454)", "c(-87.6473828702868, 41.7862165473861)", "c(-87.6750561873273, 41.7767719172303)", "c(-87.6666233031588, 41.7770234233244)", "c(-87.5499059450373, 41.731640678147)", "c(-87.5437832254962, 41.6970145984798)"), 
               PRI_NEIGH = c("Humboldt Park", "Englewood", "Englewood", "Englewood", "South Chicago", "East Side")
),
row.names = c(NA, 6L), 
class = "data.frame"
)

data_sf = data %>%
  mutate(geom = gsub(geometry,pattern="(\\))|(\\()|c",replacement = ""))%>%
  tidyr::separate(geom,into=c("lat","lon"),sep=",")%>%
  st_as_sf(.,coords=c("lat","lon"),crs=4326)
```

The `gsub` is removing any matching parentheses. We use `\\` to escape them in the regex code. The `|` indicates we want to match `(` , `)` and the `c` character. Then use `separate` to separate the remaining values in the geometry column by a comma into two new columns.

`st_as_sf` will take your lat and lon coordinates that we created in the previous step and convert to an `sf` object. I guessed on the crs.

Comment: This worked beautifully! Thanks a lot!

Comment: @ify glad to hear it! If this solution worked for you, please accept it as the answer!

Answer (score 2):

I have no idea why you seem to have a concatenate on the geometry string but, so be it. We need to remove it before operating on the data.frame.

First, here is your data.

```
library(sf)

xy.dat <- structure(list(date = c("2017-08-04", "2017-08-04", "2017-08-04", "2017-08-04", "2017-08-04", "2017-08-04"),
               is_boarded = c("0", "0", "0", "0", "1", "0"), 
               fire = c("0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0"), 
               homeless = c("0", "0", "1", "1", "0", "0"), 
               address = c("1231 N harding ave", "5942 S peoria st", "6440 S seeley ave", "6428 S paulina st", "9015 S houston ave", "10917 S buffalo ave"), 
               zip_code = c("60651", "60621", "60636", "60636", "60617", "60617"), 
               ward = c("37", "16", "16", "15", "10", "10"), 
               community_area = c("23", "68", "67", "67", "46", "52"), 
               geometry = c("c(-87.7251002085875, 41.903236038454)", "c(-87.6473828702868, 41.7862165473861)", "c(-87.6750561873273, 41.7767719172303)", "c(-87.6666233031588, 41.7770234233244)", "c(-87.5499059450373, 41.731640678147)", "c(-87.5437832254962, 41.6970145984798)"), 
               PRI_NEIGH = c("Humboldt Park", "Englewood", "Englewood", "Englewood", "South Chicago", "East Side")
               ),
          row.names = c(NA, 6L), 
          class = "data.frame"
         )
```

Now, we remove the `c` in the geometry column, add the MULTIPOINT geometry WKT and coerce to sfc object. Then we can use this sfc geometry to create an sf object from the original data.frame.

```
xy.dat$geometry <- gsub('\\c', '', xy.dat[,"geometry"]) 
  xy <- sf::st_as_sfc(paste0("MULTIPOINT",gsub("\\) \\(","\\),\\(",gsub(","," ",xy.dat$geometry))))

xy <- sf::st_sf(data.frame(xy.dat[,-9], geom=xy))
```

Comment: Thanks so much for your input! For some reason, Rstudio kept freezing when I ran this script but it seems like it could work

Answer (score 1):

Here's another way that takes advantage of your geometry column being all set to pass to `st_point` as an argument. Let's make a bunch of text `st_point` calls, and wrap them in a text `st_sfc` call and evaluate that as text and create a spatial data frame from that:

```
dsf = st_sf(d,
 geom=eval(
  parse(
   text=
     paste0("st_sfc(",paste0("st_point(",d$geometry,")",collapse=","),")")
        )
       )
      )
```